# Python - NLTK Bigram Keep <s> and </s> as one word

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to create a program to calculate bigram probabilities. My first step is to work out the combinations of a sentence.

Each of these sentences start with a `<s>` and end with a `</s>`. So lets say my example sentence was `<s> my name is python </s>`, my result should be (I have p tags because I will work out the probability after)

```
p(my | <s>)
p(name | my )
p (is | name)
p (python | is)
p (</s> | python)
```

But instead i'll get a result like:

```
Counter({('<', 's'): 1, ('s', '>'): 1, ('>', 'my'): 1, ('my', 'name'): 1, ('name', 'is'): 1, ('is', 'python'): 1, ('python', '<'): 1, ('<', '/s'): 1, ('/s', '>'): 1})
```

How would I seperate the `<s>` and `</s>` as a separate word and not split it.

My code is:

```
text = "<s> my name is python </s>" 
token = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
bigrams = ngrams(token,2)

print(Counter(bigrams))
```

**Edit**

Lets say I have a text file

```
<s> a a b b c c </s> <s> a c b c </s> <s> b c c a b </s>
```

I then open this text file and perform the following operation on it and store it in a list.

```
temp = re.split("\s+",line.rstrip('\n'))
bigramText.append(temp)
```

So now in my list I have:

```
[['<s>', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', '</s>'], ['<s>', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'c', '</s>'], ['<s>', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', '</s>']]
```

Now from this stage I want to perform calculations to get the bigram probabilities. I dont know If my initial question will help get the result but essentialy I am trying to figure out how many times those combinations occur i.e. you need to check how many times a letter appears next to the other

Answer (score 0):

You should probably write your own bigrammizer if you can split by space (which is usually a tought condition. I'm would remain I'm and not I m)

```
def custom_bigrams(l):
    return list(zip(l, l[1:]))
print(custom_bigrams(['<s>', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'python', '</s>']))
```

it prints

```
[('<s>', 'my'), ('my', 'name'), ('name', 'is'), ('is', 'python'), ('python', '</s>')]
```

To use it on your list, you have to calculate bigrams and then use the update method from Counter.

```
your_list = [['<s>', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', '</s>'], ['<s>', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'c', '</s>'], ['<s>', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', '</s>']]

c = Counter()
for x in your_list:
     c.update(custom_bigrams(x))
```

Output

```
 Counter({('b', 'c'): 3, ('<s>', 'a'): 2, ('a', 'b'): 2, ('c', 'c'): 2, ('c', '</s>'): 2, ('a', 'a'): 1, ('b', 'b'): 1, ('a', 'c'): 1, ('c', 'b'): 1, ('<s>', 'b'): 1, ('c', 'a'): 1, ('b', '</s>'): 1})
```

Comment: If my sentence was a corpus (a large text) that is stored in a list, is this approach still viable? Because you cant use a split on a list. Lets say i've done all the splitting etc and stored it in a list. What would be my approach then to get the counter of all the combinations?

Comment: If you have the lust, remove the sentance parameter and give a list instead, I am fixing it. And then to get the counter, your approach is good with the collections.Counter item

Comment: Lets say I use my own list. If i print out after using the function on it (Without the counter) i get `[(['<s>', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', '</s>'], ['<s>', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'c', '</s>']), (['<s>', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'c', '</s>'], ['<s>', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', '</s>'])]` but when i try to use the Counter function on it i get an error saying `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` but the Counter function works on your example list? How comes.

Comment: What's your exact list as an input? Because with a list of string, you got a list of tuples, and you can apply a Counter on it. Not with the list you gave me

Comment: I have made edits to the main post. I hope this clarifies further.

Comment: Is it possible to put the update within my function without making it reach a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object` ?

Comment: Infact, does the `return list(zip(l, l[1:]))` become redundant? If i just put the code you provided starting from `c = Counter()` in a function, then the function has no other purpose? I'm a bit confused

Answer (score 0):

It is normal that NLTK tokenizer makes errors when segmenting `'<s>'` and `'</s>'`
you should remove them before calling the tokenizer and then add them after tokenization.

```
text = "<s> my name is python </s>" 
clean_text = text.replace('<s>','').replace('</s>','')
token =  ['<s>'] + nltk.word_tokenize(clean_text) + ['</s>']
bigrams = ngrams(token,2)
```